# If for each point there is an iteration of $f$ which is equal to $0$ then some iteration of $f$ is identically $0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Hello fellow mathematicians,

Consider a continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0$, and for every $x\in [0,1]$ there exists $k=k(x)>0$ such that the $k$th iteration of $f$ at $x$ is equal to $0$, i.e. $f^{(k)}(x)=0$. I want to show that there exists $n>0$ such that $f^{(n)}(x)=0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.

I defined the sets $A_k=\{x\in [0,1] \mid f^{(k)}(x)=0\}$ and noticed that they are increasing and cover $[0,1]$ but it doesn't seem to help much.

Any ideas?

Comment: Refer to Primer of Real Functions by R P Boas for this and many other applications of Baire Category Theorem.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks! Do you have a precise reference?

Comment: @Nick That's the obvious thing to do but it is not clear to me how to show it is open

Comment: @Nick The $A_k$s are closed, not necessarily open, precisely because of continuity and because $A_k = \left(f^{(k)}\right)^{-1}(\{0\})$ with $\{0\}$ closed. Showing that one of them is open (in $[0,1]$) would solve the question using connectedness though.

Comment: This is not going to answer your question directly, but there might be merit in looking at the proof of the similar statement where instead of iterations you'd look at derivatives in this MathOverflow post and try to adapt one of the proofs to your case: https://mathoverflow.net/q/34059

Comment: @BrunoB , Piotr Hajlasz's answer(https://mathoverflow.net/a/296605/172294) in that link can be translated pretty much word for word to this problem (you can actually just get away with making obvious replacements - like changing 'is not a polynomial on any open interval of a point' to 'no iterate equals zero on any open interval of a point' and checking that with these replacements, the proof still goes through.

Comment: @porridgemathematics What I don't see yet is the following. In the case of polynomials, if $f$ is a polynomial of degrees $n_1$ and $n_2$ in $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ and these intervals intersect, then $f$ is a polynomial in the union $(a,b)\cup (c,d)$, and its degree is the minimum of $n_1$ and $n_2$. Now if $f^{(n_1)}(x)=0$ in $(a,b)$ and $f^{(n_2)}(x)=0$ in $(c,d)$, is it true that the smaller iteration is $0$ in the union?

Comment: Let $m$ and $M$ be the minimum and maximum of $n_1$ and $n_2$. If there is some $c$ in the union such that $f^{(m)}(c)\neq 0$, then we obtain a neighbourhood of $0$ where $f^{(M-m)}$ is $0$ and this seems to solve the problem.

Comment: I have a proof now. Thanks everyone

Comment: Maybe you could write up an answer yourself then? Only if you'd like to, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested in the comments, we want to follow one of the proofs for the problem where at each point some derivative is $0$.

Let $\Omega$ be the set of points $x\in [0,1]$ for which there is an interval $(a,b)\ni x$ and $k>0$ such that $f^{(k)}(y)=0$ for every $y\in (a,b)\cap [0,1]$. Following one of the proofs from the post we can use Baire's theorem to deduce that $\Omega$ is dense in $[0,1]$. The next step is show that $[0,1]\setminus \Omega$ has no isolated points.

If $x$ is such that there exist $a,b,n_1,n_2$ such that $f^{(n_1)}(a,x)=\{0\}$ and $f^{(n_2)}(x,b)=\{0\}$, then $f^{(n)}(a,b)=\{0\}$ by continuity, where $n=\max\{n_1,n_2\}$. However, it could be that $x$ is an isolated point and $(a,x)\cup (x,b)$ can be covered by infinitely many intervals, where at each of them some iteration of $f$ is $0$. At this point we take cases.

**First case**: There are $n_1,n_2$, overlapping $(a,b),(c,d)$ and $x\in (a,b)\cup (c,d)$ such that $f^{(n_1)}(a,b)=\{0\}$, $f^{(n_2)}(c,d)=\{0\}$ and
$f^{(m)}(x)\neq 0$, where $m=\min \{n_1,n_2\}$. In this case, let $r=|n_1-n_2|$, and note that we can find $\varepsilon>0$ such that $f^{(r)}(0,\varepsilon)=\{0\}$ by looking at the last point $y$ where $f^{(m)}(y)=0$ and using continuity. Now for every $x\in [0,1]$ we can find $k>0$ and $(a,b)\ni x$ such that $f^{(k)}(y)<\varepsilon$ for every $y\in (a,b)\cap [0,1]$. By compactness we can get a finite subcover $[0,1]\subset\cup_{i=1}^N (a_i,b_i)$, $N<\infty$, and $k_i>0$ such that $f^{(k_i)}(x)<\varepsilon$ for every $x\in (a_i,b_i)\cap [0,1]$. Then $f^{(k_i+r)}(x)=0$ for every $x\in (a_i,b_i)\cap [0,1]$. Then we just take the maximum.

**Second case**: The following is true for every $n_1,n_2$ and overlapping $(a,b),(c,d)$. If $f^{(n_1)}(a,b)=\{0\}$ and $f^{(n_2)}(c,d)=\{0\}$, then $f^{(m)}(x)=0$ for every $x\in (a,b)\cup (c,d)$, where $m=\min \{n_1,n_2\}$. In this case we are done regarding isolated points by the argument above.